# How to create a Button Dropdown ... like facebook

Tags: facebook, button, drop-down-menu

I want a Button DropDown just like facebook Dropdown Button... using javascript, Jquery ...
Is there any demo or reference website for this ...?

Like below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit Below Example

http://173.203.115.147/wordpress/html/facebook_dropdown.html

Comment: this link does not work, but I found another sample: http://sammaye.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/facebook-dropdown-menu-using-jdropdown/