# How can I create a dropdown button using jquery?

Tags: jquery, list, menu, drop-down-menu

I need a button similar to the facebook account, in the right top. A button that when clicked show a  dropdown list with options

I already tried a search in google but i can't find nothing similar.

Any idea? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two links may be what you want:

[How to create a Button Dropdown … like facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789014/how-to-create-a-button-dropdown-like-facebook)

[Facebook Style CSS JQuery drop down menus](http://sammaye.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/facebook-style-css-jquery-drop-down-menus/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not jquery, but the [YUI menu button](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example07.html) might fit your needs.  It allows you to display a simple list of text items and catch events when users click on them, or you can step out of the box and format a panel with your own custom html.  It also plays fine with jquery, not too surprisingly.